# JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript

My coding for JavaScript is not working and I can't figure out why. Can someone look it over and tell me what I am overlooking?

This is for my JavaScript assignment the link below is the assignment. Every time I have attempted to run the coding, it opens up to a blank page. But I can't see where my error(s) are. All I need is for someone to quickly read it and tell me what I can do to make it function.

https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=16uNNiooLalkm1QlszrqEPr2qqMGLjhrtQx7qCLw-7d2ftygre8GM6hyceJHj&hl=en

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var classCtr;
var nmAnswer;
var clsGrade;
var totalvalue;
var gpatotalvalue;
gpatotalvalue = 0;
totalvalue = 0;
// set up one dimensional array
var class = new Array();
classnm = 0;

do
{
  // start columns in second dimension of the array
  class[classCtr] = new Array();

 // get values from user and put in array
 class[classCtr][0] = prompt ("Enter Class Name");
 class[classCtr][1] = prompt ("Enter grade recieved");
 class[classCtr][2] = {"A":4,"B":3,"C":2,"D":1,"F":0}[class[classCtr][1]];
 class[classCtr][3] = prompt ("Enter credit hours")


 // accumulate the total value
 totalvalue = totalvalue + parseFloat(class[classCtr][3]);

 // add one to the total number of cars
 classCtr++;
 totalvalue = totalvalue + parseFloat(class[classCtr][2]);
 nmAnswer = prompt ("Do you have more classes");
} while (nmAnswer == "yes");

  // set variable that is used as counter
 clsGrade = 0;

 // print out header for content
 document.write("<H2 align='center'>Grade Point Average</H2><br>");
 document.write("<table bgcolor='Grey' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='4' width='75%'>");
 document.write("<tr>");
 document.write("<td>Class Name</td><td align='center'>Class Grade</td><td align='center'>Grade Credit</td>");
 document.write("</tr>");

// Loop through array displaying html and javascript values in the array
while (clsGrade < classnm)
  {
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write (class[classCtr][0]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td align='center'>");
  document.write (class[classCtr][1]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td align='center'>");
  document.write (class[classCtr][3]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");

  document.write("</td>");


  // increment the counter
   clsGrade++;
  }

// finish the table of data and display the total value
document.write("</Table>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<table bgcolor='grey' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='4' width='75%'>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>Total value</td><td align='center'>" + totalvalue + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>GPA</td><td align='center'>" + gpatotalvalue + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</Table>");


 //-->
</script>
</font></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could it be possible that classCtr not being initialized to anything is causing the error when initializing the second array within class[classCtr]?

Answer (score 2):

`classnm` is never set to anything other than 0...

Comment: Yeah, I think the author possibly changed the code to put the user values into the "class" Array and never changed the old logic.

Comment: @kHuynh:  Yeah, you set it to 0, but it never changes after that.  classGrade == 0 and classNm == 0 so your while loop is never run because 0 is not less than 0.

Comment: @kHuynh - yeah, you set it to 0, but then you enter a loop with this: `while (clsGrade < classnm)` which will not execute unless clsGrade is less than 0...

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code in Firefox with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension installed. It reported the following error.

```
class[classCtr] is undefined on Line 34
```

Line 34 is the following:

```
totalvalue = totalvalue + parseFloat(class[classCtr][2]);
```

This error is occurring because you increment `classCtr` on the previous line, so the call to `class[classCtr]` attempts to access something that hasn't yet been defined.

Also, `classCtr` isn't assigned an initial value, so will have the value `unassigned`. The first set of values will therefore be stored in `classCtr[undefined]`.

You'll need to initialize `classCtr` when it is declared and then increment it after you've finished handling each class.

Comment: Yet another reason to have everyone develop with firebug!  I missed that in my first glance, but there's one problem.

Comment: The problem lies before that line though:  class[classCtr] = new Array(); is like saying class["undefined"] = new Array();

Comment: What do you suggest I should use instead in order to make it valid?

Answer (score 2):

class is a javascript reserved word, rename all "class" to something else. E.g. "myClass"

Renaming "class" should make your code work, but I still see many minimal errors in your code like unclosed "head" tag, use of uninitialized variable, etc.  Suggest you review it thoroughly.