# Javascript still not working

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

I still can not get my coding to run. When I try to run the coding, a blank page shows up. Specifically, what do I need to do in order to get this simple coding to function? All I need is someone to look this over or test it and tell me what I need to get my coding to work.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var classCtr;
var nmAnswer;
var clsGrade;
var totalvalue;
var gpatotalvalue;
gpatotalvalue = 0;
totalvalue = 0;
// set up one dimensional array
var myClass = new Array();
  classnm = 0;

do
{
  // start columns in second dimension of the array
    myClass[classCtr] = new Array();

    // get values from user and put in array
    myClass[classCtr][0] = prompt ("Enter Class Name");
    myClass[classCtr][1] = prompt ("Enter grade recieved");
    myClass[classCtr][2] = {"A":4,"B":3,"C":2,"D":1,"F":0}[class[classCtr][1]];
    myClass[classCtr][3] = prompt ("Enter credit hours")


    // accumulate the total value
    totalvalue = totalvalue + parseFloat(myClass[classCtr][3]);

    // add one to the total number 
    classCtr++;
    gpatotalvalue = gpatotalvalue + parseFloat(myClass[classCtr][1]);
    nmAnswer = prompt ("Do you have more classes");
} while (nmAnswer == "yes");

  // set variable that is used as counter
    clsGrade = 0;

    // print out header for content
    document.write("<H2 align='center'>Grade Point Average</H2><br>");
    document.write("<table bgcolor='Grey' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='4' width='75%'>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>Class Name</td><td align='center'>Class Grade</td><td align='center'>Grade Credit</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");

// Loop through array displaying html and javascript values in the array
while (clsGrade == 0 && classnm == 0)
  {
     document.write("<tr>");
     document.write("<td>");
     document.write (class[clsGrade][0]);
     document.write("</td>");
     document.write("<td align='center'>");
     document.write (class[clsGrade][1]);
     document.write("</td>");
     document.write("<td align='center'>");
     document.write (class[clsGrade][3]);
     document.write("</td>");
     document.write("</tr>");

     document.write("</td>");


     // increment the counter
   clsGrade++;
  }

// finish the table of data and display the total value
document.write("</Table>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<table bgcolor='grey' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='4' width='75%'>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>Total value</td><td align='center'>" + totalvalue + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>GPA</td><td align='center'>" + gpatotalvalue + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</Table>");


 //-->
</script>
</font></body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you already know, JavaScript is very finicky - one small bo-bo will easily erase your entire page.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the JavaScript console in your browser?  It will give you a specific error if it tries to execute your code and fails.

Comment: As a programmer, you have got to be aware of debugging help. Alert boxes along the way can tell you approx where it stopped working. And also, IE has a javascript debugger inbuilt, it will tell you which line and why it stopped.

Comment: This is an updated version of the code from a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227740/javascript-is-not-working

Comment: @rlb.usa- that is very true. It's very frustrating.
@Bryan Kyle - How would I do that? I've never accessed the JavaScript console.

Comment: At the line where you declare `classnm = 0` you've got a syntax error for starters.  You can define multiple variables with the `var` command if you put commas between the declarations.  The semi-colon ends the statement.  I agree with the other sentiments as well - a JS Console like Firebug or the IE Developer will help you a ton.

Comment: @ Phil Ross - it is an updated version. And I appreciated all the help, but after hours of trying I'm still having no success is getting the code to run. I'm just experienced enough to understand why the code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Heres a working version, although I'm not sure if the GPA calculation is correct, don't have GPA's in New Zealand so not sure how its calculated. I added some comments to the code it point out where you had gone wrong :)

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var classCtr = 0; // should be initialised to 0 so it can be incremented
var nmAnswer;
var clsGrade;
var totalvalue;
var gpatotalvalue = 0;
var totalvalue = 0;
// set up one dimensional array
var myClass = new Array();

//removed some unused variables

do
{
  // start columns in second dimension of the array
    myClass[classCtr] = new Array();

    // get values from user and put in array
    myClass[classCtr][0] = prompt ("Enter Class Name");
    myClass[classCtr][1] = prompt ("Enter grade recieved");
    myClass[classCtr][2] = {"A":4,"B":3,"C":2,"D":1,"F":0}; //removed the myClass[classCtr][1] part
    myClass[classCtr][3] = prompt ("Enter credit hours")


    // accumulate the total value
    totalvalue = totalvalue + parseFloat(myClass[classCtr][3]); //had class instead of myClass

    gpatotalvalue = gpatotalvalue + parseFloat(myClass[classCtr][2][ myClass[classCtr][1] ] ); //moved this line above the classCtr++; line so you weren't accessing an undefined variable, there some changes here to access the myClass[classCtr][2] object value correctly..

    // add one to the total number 
    classCtr++;

    nmAnswer = prompt ("Do you have more classes");
} while (nmAnswer == "yes");

  // set variable that is used as counter
    clsGrade = 0;

    // print out header for content
    document.write("<H2 align='center'>Grade Point Average</H2><br>");
    document.write("<table bgcolor='Grey' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='4' width='75%'>");
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td>Class Name</td><td align='center'>Class Grade</td><td align='center'>Grade Credit</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");

// Loop through array displaying html and javascript values in the array
while (myClass[clsGrade]) //the previous conditional would only out put the first "persons" grades so changed this to loop through until all peoples grades
  {
     document.write("<tr>");
     document.write("<td>");
     document.write (myClass[clsGrade][0]); //had class instead of myClass
     document.write("</td>");
     document.write("<td align='center'>");
     document.write (myClass[clsGrade][1]);//had class instead of myClass
     document.write("</td>");
     document.write("<td align='center'>");
     document.write (myClass[clsGrade][3]);//had class instead of myClass
     document.write("</td>");
     document.write("</tr>");

     document.write("</td>");


     // increment the counter
    clsGrade++;
  }

// finish the table of data and display the total value
document.write("</Table>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<table bgcolor='grey' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='4' width='75%'>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>Total value</td><td align='center'>" + totalvalue + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("<tr>");
document.write("<td>GPA</td><td align='center'>" + gpatotalvalue + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
document.write("</Table>");


 //-->
</script>
</font></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I could hug you! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! This is so kind of you to do, you don't understand how much I deeply appreciate this! It works and with your comments I understand why. You are amazing! Many thanks!

Comment: Although putting the entire array of grades in each item makes no sense at all. You removed the code that picks out a single grade from the array.

Comment: Ahh yeah true, yeah I didn't want to spend to long with the code, its pretty knarly.

Answer (score 0):

In this line you used `class` instead of `myClass`:

```
myClass[classCtr][2] = {"A":4,"B":3,"C":2,"D":1,"F":0}[myClass[classCtr][1]];
```

In these lines you were increasing `classCtr` first, which meant that you get an undefined value as you are accessing an element beyond the end of the array:

```
gpatotalvalue = gpatotalvalue + parseFloat(myClass[classCtr][1]);
classCtr++;
```

Comment: As pointed out in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227740/javascript-is-not-working#3227788) to the earlier version of this question, `classCtr` isn't actually initialized. In addition to changing the order of those lines, `classCtr` needs to be set to an initial value before it is first used.